# JavaScript convert DateTime:"2017:10:01 19:06:57" string to ISO date string

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the following

```
DateTime:"2017:10:01 19:06:57"
```

To ISO date/time format I tried doing to  `image.exif.DateTime.toISOString()`

But ran into an error, am I missing something?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Almog Koren Are you sure your format is correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace the first two colons by dashes. You can achieve that by `.replace(/:(?=.* )/g, '-')`, which in that case has the same effect as `.replace(':', '-').replace(':', '-')`.
Additionally you have to replace the space by the letter T.

```js
var dateString = "2017:10:01 19:06:57";

var dateStringISO = dateString.replace(/:(?=.* )/g, '-').replace(' ', 'T');
// (timezone indicator is optional)
console.log(dateStringISO); // That format fulfills ISO 8601.

var date = new Date(dateString.replace(/:(?=.* )/g, '-'));
// here you could manipulate your date
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If, your browser doesn't support toISOString() method. try below code

```
function ISODate(d) {
        function pad(n) {return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
        return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
             + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
             + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
             + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
             + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
             + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
    }
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(ISODate(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that any JS implementation will understand the format:

```
2017:10:01 19:06:57
```

Eg. in Chrome's dev tools:

```
08:28:08.649 new Date("2017:10:01 19:06:57")
08:28:08.649 Invalid Date
```

(Colons are typically time separators and no element of a time can be 2017.)

Therefore you're going to need to parse it yourself. Something like:

```
var year = parseInt(str.substring(0, 4));
var month = parseInt(str.substring(5, 7));
// etc for day, hour, min, sec
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
```

(This will create to a local time, if you want UTC then use `Date.UTC` rather than the constructor.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out, this is the format that is returned by the EXIF data from an image not sure why it's like that.